# Mandate Android Application to Start Portrait Only, BUT ability to rotate when running

Tags: android, orientation

I have an application that I want to start only in portrait,  but once it has begun allow for configuration change.  The content of the landscape mode is a map image that relates to the information on the portrait view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could start you activity in portrait mode using

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.FrmSignature"
  android:label="@string/frmsignature_lblTitle"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
/>
```

and then, inside your code, you can link the orientation change to device position [setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your Manifest file.

Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait` to your activity Tag in which you'd like to show Portrait..

```
<activity android:name=".Keydets_Main" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/keydets_icon" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

If you add this for **Particular Activity** , only that activity will comes in Portrait Mode.

If you Specify inside of Application Tag it will applicable for whole app.